# Ruby on Rails SMTP send mail fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, sendmail

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => "587",
    :domain => "gmail.com",
    :authentication => "plain",
    :user_name => "myusername@gmail.com",
    :password => "mypassword",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "myusername@gmail.com"
  def confirm(email)
    @message = "Thank you for confirmation!"
    mail(:to => email, :subject => "Registered")
  end
end
```

I type UserMailer.confirm(“someone@example.org”).deliver in rails console and it delivers out. But i cannot received any mail from the target mail box ....
The google acount in the setting is my personal google acount, and i use the same username and password.

Comment: Set `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` and try again.

Comment: "Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at" I pretty sure the username and password were both correct .... ==

Comment: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha - press 'Continue' and try to send mail again, or search simular questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now the mail can deliver out. But it still have no response in the target mail box....